Right approach to create an architecture for multiparty video chat
I'm implementing a video chat app for multi-parties. In my app I used socket.io for event management and peer.js for offering connection between peers.
I implemented the mesh architecture in a way that, when anyone in a room starts a call, every peer is calling to every other peer in useEffect hook. So, suppose if A, B, C is in a room, then all of them is calling to other two peers. In this case when A is offering, B is answering and also calling back to A and therefore A is answering. If I'm not wrong, the second offering replaces the first one, right? And when peer D is joining later and calling to others, all four of them now again call each other which is not efficient, I think. So how can you manage to implement it efficiently so that existing calls remain and new offerings being made, or can you please tell me a better convenient approach? Thanks in advance.

There's good reason real world multiparty chat doesn't use mesh architecture and instead puts a single mux/demux point in the middle. You don't want to multiply upstream bandwidth needed by each client by the number of other clients in the call. You also don't want clients to be able to "cheat" and send a different steam to each party present (say, telling someone A while the lawyer for that person sees B).

That said, this is generally too broad and open to different interpretations of design priorities to be a good fit for Stack Overflow -- our focus is on narrow, specific questions; figuring out which priorities you care about in designing an overall architecture is part of what will distinguish your product from competitors; come here once you've gotten to the nitty gritty of implementation and have a narrow, specific technical problem.
